# What are the things that must be taken care of before deploying a cakephp website

Tags: security, cakephp, deployment

Im just done with a cakephp website, but im still in a doubt on what are the things that I must take care of, before making this website live.
Since it is a big application that require users to Register and Login and to manage their accounts. Any sort of help is appreciated.
Thanx.

Comment: If Your users can edit some data then You can use SecurityComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harden instillation, set production mode if you are using different SQL services, disable php error reporting, enable caching, disable and remove all client side debugging like DebugKit, make sure any comments in your html will not give hackers an advantage like printing variables.

Php frameworks can be resource hogs.  I think the last but most important is to test server with some generated traffic.  There are services that can do this for you.  You may need to separate resources or set up an additional server for SQL if you expect a lot of traffic.

There may be a couple other things you might want to do.. Just browse your core.php and bootstrap.php. Make sure everything is working is correctly for production environment.

Comment: thanx for reply..just want to know one more thing..
What are the loop holes that can exist and must take care of??

Comment: Actually security is pretty well handled in cakephp.  If you really want to lock things down change your `Security.level` to high, this will lock sessions to a single browser window and logout the user if that user is logged into another session.  The items I suggested above are pretty through.  Idk about any 'loopholes' per se, but those will definitely make it difficult to crack your system.  Now, we're just talking about the framework itself, there are many things as a developer you could have done to leave your application open to attack.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) answering directly that:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are some common but important things to be taken care of before making cake website live.

1. Check for read/write permissions on desired folders.
2. Check for images,js files and css files you need on your website .
3. Check for writable temp folder and clear cache.
4. Set debug level to 0.
5. Make sure database connectivity works fine.